# Can Mathematica return the order of an element in $S_n$

Tags: functions, group-theory

I want to input an element like `Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}]` and I want *Mathematica* to return 6, the order of this element in $S_5$.

Comment: I don't know if this is built in, but if you have your element as disjoint cycles then the order is just the LCM of the lengths.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot seem to extract the cycle lengths from the element  Cycles[{{1,2},{3,4,5}]

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Just replace the Head with `List` and manipulate it as a list, if you're finding it hard to think about a `Cycles` object. An alternative (horrible) method is `PermutationGroup[{perm}] // GroupOrder`.

Comment: Thanks Patrick Stevens, but I do not know how to "just replace the Head with List".

Comment: Check the refguide for `Apply`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`PermutationOrder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PermutationOrder.html) function:

```
In[1]:= elt = Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}];

In[2]:= PermutationOrder[elt]
Out[2]= 6
```

This is indeed the answer you expect, and the smallest power you can raise `elt` to and get the identity permutation.

```
In[3]:= PermutationPower[elt, #] & /@ Range[6]
Out[3]= {Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}], Cycles[{{3, 5, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}], 
         Cycles[{{3, 4, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 5, 4}}], Cycles[{}]}
```

It also matches the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles, as mentioned in @Daniel Lichtblau's comment above. Since the permutation is represented as a list of cycles (themselves lists) [wrapped in the head `Cycle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html), we can pull them out using `First`, then use [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) to find the `Length` of each cycle, and finally [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) the `LCM` function to the list:

```
In[4]:= Apply[LCM] @* Map[Length] @* First@elt
Out[4]= 6
```

The `@*` operator is a neat new shorthand for function [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html).